# About map properties to java class in spring boot 2

Tags: spring-boot

I want to convert properties to  map, see below

```
field2ZhNameMap.platform=平台
```

==>

```
private Map<String,String> field2ZhNameMap;
```

In Spring boot 1.5.6 start the app in tomcat it's OK, but use sprint boot 2.0.0.M7 start the app in tomcat I got below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under '' to com.foo.bar.util.Field2ZhNameProperties
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:227)


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PropertyName must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasLength(Assert.java:233)
    at org.springframework.boot.origin.PropertySourceOrigin.<init>(PropertySourceOrigin.java:41)
```

After debuging source code I found start the app in tomcat it has a `JndiPropertySource` which caused above problem. So I have to explicitly disable `JndiPropertySource` by `specify spring.jndi.ignore=true in a spring.properties` to solve this problem.

In addition I found these classes like `Binder` do not exist in 1.5.6, it seems it has a big change from 1.5.6 to 2.0.0. So I want to know if has some documents record these change and guide how to correctly map properties to java class in spring boot 2?

Answer (score 0):

For me, upgrade to Spring Boot `2.0.1.RELEASE` on Tomcat `8.5.30` resolved `PropertyName must not be empty`